# How to execute a docker-compose command from within a Cypress test

Tags: docker, makefile, cypress

The root of my app project contains my docker-compose and Makefile, plus a folder called apps. Within apps is api and frontend. My Cypress installation is within the frontend folder.

I would like to be able to run a command `cy.exec('make reset-fixtures')` from within Cypress. This returns a "No rule to make target reset-fixtures" error, which I figured might be because I am executing from a folder that is deeper in the tree than my Makefile. So I changed my command to `cy.exec('cd ../.. && make reset-fixtures')` which yielded the following:

```
Stderr:
the input device is not a TTY
make[1]: *** [reset-fixtures] Error 1
```

What is the best way to be able to execute these make commands from within Cypress?

EDIT: This is the make command:

```
reset-fixtures:     
@docker-compose exec mongodb /scripts/reset-fixtures.sh
```

Comment: That error is not being printed by make.  It's being printed by whatever command is being run in the recipe for the target `reset-fixtures`.  Since you haven't shown that rule or the command that make printed before that error, there's not much more we can say about it except it apparently expects stdin to be a terminal, and it's not.

Comment: This is the make recipe:
`reset-fixtures:
 @docker-compose exec mongodb /scripts/reset-fixtures.sh`

Comment: Please edit your question rather than add comments: comments cannot be formatted properly.  Are you invoking `make` by itself, or are you providing other arguments particularly `-j`?  It seems that one of the operations being invoked requires stdin to be a TTY.  If you invoke the command `docker-compose exec mongodb /scripts/reset-fixtures.sh </dev/null` to take stdin from `/dev/null` instead of the terminal, does it work or do you get the same input device error?

Comment: It looks like it's the same input device error. I'm not using -j, what does that do?

Comment: `-j` updates targets (that don't depend on each other) in parallel.  Because multiple recipes are run at the same time, only one of them (essentially randomly) will get the stdin and the rest will not.  However as best as I'm aware when run serially (without `-j`) GNU make gives each command it invokes the same stdin it received.  So I'm not sure what the problem is here.  If you write a rule `check_tty: ; test -t 0 && echo is a tty` then run `make check_tty` does it say `is a tty`?  If so then it doesn't seem to be a make problem, at least not directly.

Comment: When I run that command from my terminal I do get `is a tty` but when I run it from within my Cypress test (as `cy.exec('cd ../.. && make check_tty') `) I get `Information about the failure:
Code: 2

Stdout:
test -t 0 && echo is a tty
Stderr:
make[1]: *** [check_tty] Error 1`

Comment: It looks like the "Cypress test" is closing stdin on the processes that it invokes via `cy.exec`.  You can prove this by changing your exec to something like `cy.exec('test -t 0 && echo is a tty')` and see what you get.  This is not a make issue: you'll have to discuss with Cypress folks.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was using the `-T` option with docker-compos exec. This prevents the use of TTY:

```
-T, --no-TTY docker compose exec     Disable pseudo-TTY allocation. By default docker compose exec allocates a TTY.
```

This would make it look like the following:

cypress test

```js
cy.exec('(cd ../; make your_command)')
```

Makefile

```
your_command:
  docker-compose exec -T your_container path_to_executable
```